# Looking for a more elegant LINQ solution

Tags: c#, sql, linq, npgsql

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to retrieve the data I am after. I need to get a list of all of the most recent children by ParentId coupled with all parent entries that do NOT have children. I have created a visual guide to illustrate what the response should be.

The query needs to remain as IQueryable until ALL sorting and paging is completed. 
`Last` and `LastOrDefault` are not supported by LINQ to Entities (as stated by the error messages I have received while using them).

Using `First` or `FirstOrDefault` will return the error "`This method or operation is not implemented`"

Original Data:

```
-------------------------------
- Id - ParentId - CreatedDate -
-------------------------------
-  1 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  2 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  3 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  4 -        1 -  07/02/2013 -
-  5 -        2 -  07/03/2013 -
-  6 -        2 -  07/04/2013 -
-  7 -        1 -  07/05/2013 -
-------------------------------
```

Data returned by query

```
-------------------------------
- Id - ParentId - CreatedDate -
-------------------------------
-  3 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  6 -        2 -  07/04/2013 -
-  7 -        1 -  07/05/2013 -
-------------------------------
```

Currently, my LINQ query looks like this:

```
// Retrieves parent records with NO children.
var q1 = myTable
    .Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
    .Except(myTable
                .Where(x => myTable
                                .Any(c => (c.ParentId == x.Id))));

// Retrieves most recent child records for each parentId
var q2 =
    (from a in myTable
     join b in
         (myTable.Where(a => a.ParentId != null)
                            .GroupBy(a => a.ParentId)
                            .Select(b => new { ParentId = b.Key, CreatedDate = b.Max(t => t.CreatedDate) }))
     on a.ParentId equals b.ParentId
     where a.CreatedDate == b.CreatedDate
     select a);

q1 = q1.Union(q2);
```

The back-end is using Npgsql2 with PostgreSQL. I am looking for a more elegant solution for this query. I am very new to LINQ and would like to optimize this.

Sorting code (sloppy, but jTable returns these strings):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sorting) || sorting.Equals("Name ASC")) {
    q1 = q1.OrderBy(p => p.Customer.Name);
} else if (sorting.Equals("Name DESC")) {
    q1 = q1.OrderByDescending(p => p.Customer.Name);
} else if (sorting.Equals("Date ASC")) {
    q1 = q1.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate);
} else if (sorting.Equals("Date DESC")) {
    q1 = q1.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate);
}
```

Paging code:

```
var result = pageSize > 0
           ? q1.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList()
           : q1.ToList();
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of a way it's going to get much better.  I don't think the SQL is going to be more optimal if you can get this into one query.  BOTH queries you already have are pretty advanced LINQ, so you can take some pride in having gotten them to work as they are now.  :)

Comment: Are you trying to get the query to run faster or refactor into one IQueryable? On the speed side I think it might be best to make a View and select from that instead. On the query side, I think it makes logical sense how you've split things out currently :-)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @AndrewWalters, The performance seems to be OK. As it is now, it takes about 50 ms uncached to form and execute the query against a table of 1000 rows. The problem occurs when I page it after sorting by date. The SQL created after the sort includes an identifier that does not exist in the rest of the query. This causes the query to fail. I figure being able to rewrite it would give me a different outcome.

Comment: Could be a driver issue, I've had queries explode in Oracle before that had perfectly good linq. Post up your paging/sorting code if you don't mind

Comment: Very stupid question - In your example, your `Id` seems to be increasing with date - Is that the case in your full dataset or just what you put in the sample data? If it is the case, the you don't really need to look at the date column at all....

Comment: I have added the paging and sorting code as requested. I posted this part of the issue to the Npgsql forums to see if they could help out.

Comment: @JohnBustos Excellent point. I have considered this, but am not 100% sure this will be the case for very long.

Comment: If you're using Npgsql, your not using LINQ to SQL which is a different provider (please update your tags and question title). The query generation is the responsibility of the provider and appears to be the source of your problem.

Comment: @JimWooley, I've updated the tag and title. I have already posted to the Npgsql tracker. Finding an alternative way will give me the possibility of a working solution without waiting for a potential bug fix.

Comment: @AndrewWalters What do you mean by "make a View and select from that instead?"

Comment: @orbv Database view, if you let SQL do the complicated joins it's usually faster. If it's still slow you can always add some caching on the web end. Since you're having issues with the LINQ query exploding view may be best anyway because you will be able to actually get the data you want

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping:

Mock data:

```
public class Entry {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int? ParentId { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }   
};

 var list = new List<Entry> {
  new Entry{ Id = 1, ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 1) },
  new Entry{ Id = 2, ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 1) },
  new Entry{ Id = 3, ParentId = null, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 1) },
  new Entry{ Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 2) },
  new Entry{ Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 3) },
  new Entry{ Id = 6, ParentId = 2, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 4) },
  new Entry{ Id = 7, ParentId = 1, Date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 5) }
};
```

Query:

```
var query = from l in list
            group l by l.ParentId into g
            select new {
                Items = g.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Last()
            };

var res = query.OrderBy(x => x.Items.Id).Select(x => x.Items).ToList();
```

LinqPad result:

```
Id  ParentId  Date 
3   null      01.07.2013 0:00:00 
6   2         04.07.2013 0:00:00 
7   1         05.07.2013 0:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using `Last`, `LastOrDefault`, `First`, or `FirstOrDefault` will not work with my provider while in `IQueryable`. I need to keep the query in `IQueryable` until all of the sorting and paging is completed as to reduce the amount of objects retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a different query, still in two phases

```
var firstQuery = myTable.Select(p => new { p.ID, ParentID = p.ParentID ?? p.ID, p.CreatedDate })
                                         .GroupBy( p => p.ParentID).Select( q => new
                                         {
                                            el = q.OrderByDescending( k => k.CreatedDate).Take(1)
                                         }).SelectMany(t => t.el);

        var result = dc.TabellaId_ParentId.Where(p => test.Select(q => q.ID).Contains(p.ID));
```